# error using cmake with llvm

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to make a very basic skeleton code, [this one](https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton), compile on Ubuntu 16.04. Here's all I have installed globally on the system:

`clang:`

```
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /usr/local/cuda
```

`& llvm-3.8 and lldb-3.8 packages`.

The error I am getting on using cmake is :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/llvm-3.8/cmake/LLVMConfig.cmake:178 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /usr/share/llvm/cmake/LLVMExports.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/llvm-3.8/cmake/LLVMConfig.cmake:181 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /usr/share/llvm/cmake/LLVM-Config.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kapil/Projects/CppProjects/hacking-llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am a beginner at using llvm (dont know about their cmake packaging structure) and don't know how to remove the error. I checked this error on google and several people have reported the bug, but I couldn't parse and get some information on how to deal with it. Please help.

Comment: Question with the same problem, but hasn't resolved yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171543/error-when-using-cmake-with-llvm. Bugreport for Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819072. As fat as I understand, it is fixed for `llvm-3.9`.