# Unable to link LLVM compiler tutorial program without building LLVM with RTTI

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

So I'm trying to follow along with the [LLVM compiler tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html) and I'm trying to build the toy example using CMake instead of `llvm-config`. Because of [an issue with Ubuntu's packaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171543/error-when-using-cmake-with-llvm), I've decided to build LLVM from source and link to that. So I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/abenkhadra/llvm-pass-tutorial) to build LLVM 3.7.1 from source. I copy-pasted the Chapter 3 source code from LLVM's `examples/Kaleidoscope` directory (since the tutorial linked above recommends doing so for the specific version of LLVM you use) and attempted to build it with the following `CMakeLists.txt`, adapted heavily from [this](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project(llvm-test-project)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")
message(STATUS "LLVM built with RTTI? ${LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI}")

add_executable(toy toy.cpp)
set_property(TARGET toy PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs core support)
target_link_libraries(toy ${llvm_libs})
message(STATUS "LLVM linked to: ${llvm_libs}")
```

However, when I try to configure and build it, I get the following linker error:

```
undefinted reference to `typeinfo for llvm:CmpInst`
```

After attempting to link to other libraries other than core and support, I decided to try re-building LLVM with RTTI enabled, and sure enough, it compiles and links successfully when I add `-DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON` to the LLVM `cmake` invocation.

Is it possible to build LLVM without RTTI and still successfully link it to the Kaleidoscope examples? It seems strange that RTTI would be needed without any mention of such from either the tutorial or the LLVM CMake documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Turns out that I my project was being built by default with RTTI, so it only linked properly when LLVM was also being built with RTTI. Adding the `-fno-rtti` compile flag fixed the problem.