# Linking LLVM causes gcov to fail

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, llvm, gcov

Passing `--coverage` to gcc while also linking LLVM causes an `` undefined reference to `__gcov_exit' `` error from the linker. I've set up a fresh project to try to isolate this problem. You can [view the source on github](https://github.com/Kerndog73/gcov_error) and [inspect the compiler output on Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/Kerndog73/gcov_error).

This is the difference between a coverage and a non-coverage build

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--coverage"
```

This is the difference between an LLVM and a non-LLVM build

```
target_link_libraries(Test
        PUBLIC
        LLVMCore
)
```

The `LLVM` job succeeds. The `Coverage` job succeeds. The `LLVM + Coverage` job fails with this error

```
undefined reference to `__gcov_exit'
```

Comment: What is the end goal here? Use of the *llvm* build tools (compiler, linker, ...) or only link  your test executable with *libLLVM*? What is the toolset that it's expected to work with? Also what's the environment? I assume *travis* (*btw*, I didn't work with it) is for demo / reproduction purposes only (although from my *PoV* it introduces an extra complexity level).

Comment: @CristiFati I’m writing a compiler. I have a coverage build on Travis. The coverage build broke when I started working on the LLVM IR generation (a month ago). I reproduced the problem in a test repo. Now I’m asking how I can both link LLVM and run test coverage.

Comment: I'll try reproduce it outside *travis*. I see that you're using *g++7* as a compiler. Is this the intent? So, the error appears only if *LINK\_WITH\_LLVM* is set?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--coverage" -DLINK_WITH_LLVM=YES`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Notes**:

- Check [[CMake 3.13]: CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) for details regarding which env var affects which *cmake* var - as you figured out in your (deleted) answer
- Only noticed *cxx_std_17* from *CMake 3.**8***, so you might want to update your *cmake_minimum_required*
- Forked your *repo* to [[GitHub]: CristiFati/gcov_error - An attempt to reproduce the gcov/llvm linker error](https://github.com/CristiFati/gcov_error) and did some debugging on it

  - **Beware, I might delete it someday**
- Was able to get my head around [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org), it's **a real gold-mine**

At the beginning I thought that it would be a trivial fix (something related to *-fprofile-arcs*, *-ftest-coverage*, *-lgcov* flags) as noted in [[Man7]: GCC(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) (*--coverage* option), but it wasn't.
I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my *Ubuntu 16 pc064* *VM* (although *Travis* is very nice, it's kind of slow for debugging purposes (especially when due to rushing one might forget or add an extra character when editing :) ) and also it doesn't offer the same access level that a local machine does,) because the environment:

- *CMake 3.5.1*
- *GCC 5.4.0*
- *LLVM 3.8.0*

is pretty far away from what's on the *Travis* *Docker* image. I must mention that neither I tried building the packages from sources (that would probably have caused lots of headaches), nor did I try downloading them from the repositories where they are downloaded during *CI* builds (didn't even check if those repos are public). Anyway the *VM* was pretty much unusable because:

- I couldn't reproduce the issue (after some minor changes to adapt to older tools), everything worked
- **More**: I ran into [[SO]: Error when using CMake with LLVM (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033716/4788546)

It was eating me alive, so I ended up building ***48*** freaking times (on *Travis*) in order to get it working, and that is only because I failed to notice the obvious.

##### The problem

For each of the 3 configurations I'm going to paste the compile and link (*G++*) commands generated (from **your** build: [[Travis CI]: Kerndog73/gcov_error - Build #24](https://travis-ci.org/Kerndog73/gcov_error/builds/474281524))

1. *LLVM*:

   > ```bash
   > /usr/bin/g++-7  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/usr/lib/llvm-7/include  -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/travis/build/Kerndog73/gcov_error/main.cpp
   > /usr/bin/g++-7    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o Test  -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMCore.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lz -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -lpthread -lm /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMDemangle.a
   > ```
2. *Coverage*:

   > ```bash
   > /usr/bin/g++-7  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/usr/lib/llvm-7/include  --coverage   -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/travis/build/Kerndog73/gcov_error/main.cpp
   > /usr/bin/g++-7  --coverage  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o Test
   > ```
3. *LLVM* + *Coverage*:

   > ```bash
   > /usr/bin/g++-7  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/usr/lib/llvm-7/include  --coverage   -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/travis/build/Kerndog73/gcov_error/main.cpp
   > /usr/bin/g++-7  --coverage  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o Test  -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMCore.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lz -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -lpthread -lm /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMDemangle.a
   > ```

After lots of ghosts chasing, I noticed ***-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8*** being passed to the linker when *LLVM* is included. *GCC 4.8* **is** installed on the *Docker*, so apparently *GCC **7.4*** was used for compilation, and *GCC **4.8*** for linking, which is ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*.
I'm also pasting the *Collect* command (closer to the linker) from a slight variation (with *-v*) of ***#3.*** (all the libraries specified with *-l** and without the full path (e.g. *-lgcov*, *-lgcc_s*, *-lgcc*) have the **wrong** version because will be picked up from the wrong directory):

> ```bash
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccyDh97q.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o Test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../.. CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMCore.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lz -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -lpthread /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libLLVMDemangle.a -lstdc++ -lm -lgcov -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.0
> ```

Some test commands placed in *.travis.yml*'s *after_script* section, yielded the following output:

> ```
> $ _GCOV_LIB7=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcov.a
> $ (nm -S ${_GCOV_LIB7} 2>/dev/null | grep __gcov_exit) || echo ${_GCOV_LIB7}
> 0000000000001e40 000000000000008b T __gcov_exit
> $ _GCOV_LIB48=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcov.a
> $ (nm -S ${_GCOV_LIB48} 2>/dev/null | grep __gcov_exit) || echo ${_GCOV_LIB48}
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcov.a
> ```

So, *LibGCC* (*libgcov.a*) was modified somewhere between the 2 involved versions (***__gcov_exit*** symbol was added), and *G++* knew it has one but *Ld* didn't provide it (because of the wrong *lib*) hence the error.

Now, **why** does *LLVM* add this library search path, I don't know (probably because it was built with *GCC 4.8* - or *smth* close to it), but here's what I can think of:

1. *LLVM* is not meant to be used with *GCC 7* (although I didn't find any such restriction while quickly browsing [[LLVM]: Getting Started with the LLVM System](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html))
2. A bug in *LLVM* (considering the other issue that I ran into, I tend to think this is the winner)

I found ways for both of them:

1. Use an older *G++* (*v4.8* - installed by default on the *Docker*)

   - `export CXX=g++` (might even not be necessary)
   - *G++* (**not** *CMake* this time) doesn't know about *cxx_std_17*, so the easiest way is to remove the afferent *target_compile_features* (the drawback is that code won't be *C++17* "compliant")
2. Since I don't know how to "undo" passing the (faulty) library search path, the workaround that I came up with is to specify the correct one **before** it.

   *CMakeLists.txt*:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
   project(gcov_test)

   find_package(LLVM 7.0.0 REQUIRED CONFIG)
   message(STATUS "Found LLVM: ${LLVM_DIR} ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")

   add_executable(Test
       "main.cpp"
   )

   target_compile_features(Test
       PUBLIC cxx_std_17
   )

   target_include_directories(Test
       PUBLIC ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   )

   target_compile_definitions(Test
       PUBLIC ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS}
   )

   if(LINK_WITH_LLVM)
       # @TODO - cfati: Everything in this block is to avoid hardcoding default libgcc path (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7)
       set(_COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER_TEXT "COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=")
       execute_process(
           COMMAND bash -c "$0 -v 2>&1 | grep ${_COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER_TEXT} | sed s/${_COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER_TEXT}//" "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
           OUTPUT_VARIABLE _GAINARIE_COLLECT_TMP_VAR
       )
       get_filename_component(_GAINARIE_GCC_DEFAULT_PATH ${_GAINARIE_COLLECT_TMP_VAR} DIRECTORY)
       set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L${_GAINARIE_GCC_DEFAULT_PATH}")
       #set (GCCOPT "${GCCOPT} -L${_GAINARIE_GCC_DEFAULT_PATH}")
       # @TODO END
       target_link_libraries(Test
           PUBLIC LLVMCore
       )
   endif()
   ```

   **Note**: I tried to come up with something more elegant (I'm sure that it is), but I couldn't (tried using *CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES*, *target_link_libraries*, *link_directories* and a few more) at this point.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for spending so much of your own free time on this! It’s really appreciated. I’ll see if I can implement your solution in my real project.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it helps. I was able to successfully build (and run the dummy *.exe*) in both cases.

Comment: Passing build with a coverage report. You've earnt yourself 100 reputation!