# When --coverage flag is added while compiling, linker fails printing - "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, code-coverage, linker-errors, gcov

I have a simple daemon program -

https://gist.github.com/RAvenGEr/9563c051de35662d64baf26a8cd66d2e

I have added a --coverage flag in makefile as below

`CC  = g++`

`CFLAGS  = -I. -Wall --coverage`

`all: daemon-name clean`

`daemon-name: daemon-name.o`
     `$(CC) -o $@ $^`
`chmod 700 daemon-name`

`daemon-name.o: daemon-name.cpp`
    `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<`

`clean:`
    `rm *.o`

When I compile the program I get -

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

`"_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_writeout in daemon-name.o`

`"_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_writeout in daemon-name.o`

`"_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_writeout in daemon-name.o`

`"_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_writeout in daemon-name.o`

`"_llvm_gcda_summary_info", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_writeout in daemon-name.o`
  `"_llvm_gcov_init", referenced from:`
      `___llvm_gcov_init in daemon-name.o`

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Note that program is compiling and linking correctly without --coverage flag, but I really need to see coverage of daemon-name.cpp

I believe the cause of error is linker somehow not interpreting --coverage flag. How can I add the --coverage flag to the linker in order to see code coverage.

Comment: Maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626481/linking-llvm-causes-gcov-to-fail/54032670#54032670.